# how to convert one column data into multiple rows in ms access using ms access query

Tags: ms-access

What I have in ms access table is below

1. **Number**   **purchase**
2. 101           product1 product2 product3
3. 102           product1 product2

And  I want to convert it into below format using ms access query(using select query only)

1. **Number**   **purchase**
2. 101           product1
3. 101           product2
4. 101           Product3
5. 102           product1
6. 102           product2

I am not able to the conversion column into rows ,in  table i have a column in which multiple values are separated by the space and I  have to convert it into row by row  in ms access select query 
please any one can help me

Comment: So... what have you tried? As you are new, I strongly advice you reading our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use code then it is quite easy
Use the  following code to count the number of spaces

```
Public Function calculateSplits(InputRecord as String) 
Dim recordWithoutSpaces as String
Dim noOfSpaces as Integer

recordWithoutSpaces = Replace(InputRecord," ","")
noOfSpaces =Len(InputRecord) -Len(recordWithoutSpaces )
calculateSplits = noOfSpaces 
End Function
```

Then use the following code to Split the Records

```
Public Function ParseText(TextIn As String, x As Byte, Optional MyDelim As String) As Variant
On Error Resume Next
If Len(MyDelim) > 0 Then
   ParseText = Split(TextIn, MyDelim)(x)
Else
   ParseText = Split(TextIn, " ")(x)
End If
End Function
```

Then you just create a function that reads your table and appends records to another table splitted as you want

According to your latest code

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim myDelim As String
Dim strSQL As String ' want to insert the ParseText value into the new cust_info table
Dim ParseText As String
myDelim = " "
If Len(myDelim) > 0 Then
      For i = 0 To 3 ' <-- n+1 CalculateSplits e.g if you have found 3 splits (spaces) then i =0 to 4
         ParseText = Split("101 product1 product2 product3", myDelim)(i)
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO cust_info([cust_id], [cust_prods]) VALUES ('" & i + 1 & "','" & ParseText & "');"
         DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
       Next


End If

End Sub
```

Just pay attention to my comment about the upper threshold of i counter.

Comment: Hi John,

This is the new code which i added to you ParseText function,

...
If Len(MyDelim) > 0 Then
        For I = 0 To x
            ParseText = Split(TextIn, MyDelim)(I)
            Dim strSQL As String
            ' want to insert the ParseText value into the new cust_info table 
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO cust_info([cust_id], [cust_prods]) VALUES (1 ,‘”&ParseText&”’);"
            DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        Next
...

The insert statement above is not working, please help me out

Thanks,
Amay

Comment: Take a look at my revised answer

Comment: Thanks john your code is working completely fine
but facing a new issue insert query is not working because i dont know how to form the connection string and install the ms access driver can you please guide to me

Comment: what ms access driver?

Comment: when we inserting into ms access table we need the ms access driver should be installed
i am using below constring
constring = "Driver={MicrosoftAccessDriver(*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\Upendra\Downloads\Compressed\AgeRange.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
con.Open constring
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO emp_details([emp_no], [emp_info]) VALUES ('" & I + 1 & "','" & ParseText & "');"
         con.Execute strSQL
         DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
but when i am selected from emp_details table nothing is got inseted

Comment: Are you trying to another database to execute the query?...if so let me know....why don't you link the tables?

Comment: no i have created  emp_details table in the same database

Comment: so why all the trouble with drivers and connections ?

Comment: yes i am also thing the problem with drivers and connections
please see this link 
http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32976

Comment: I am under the impression that the driver won't allow these kind of operations according to this http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/16466 but i must admit i haven't read it thoroughly

Comment: or tell me the to do above task using only select query so wont mess with the drivers

Comment: i will need a full description of the current situation as what software you have installed, exactly what you are trying to do..what you have tried so far and of course a bigger set of data to get an idea and ....i am afraid i am not sure i can help you...also give me some kind of link..the comment in SO is way too limited....and maybe you should try to post a new question

Comment: i don't know if it is allowed by SO...create some kind a report and send me the link to take a look......

Comment: can we do above task using only select query without using the vb script
if possible then my problem will solve it